# Possible angular deployment options

Tags: angularjs, angular, iis, server

I am attempting to set up an angular app on my iis server network.

It's made up of
Server a - angular application - no Internet access - access to server b
Server b - database - no Internet access 
Outside computers - Internet access-no access to server b

The angular app makes references to server b and this works when run on the server a machine but not when accessing from outside computers.

My question is whether this is a possible set up for an angular application or whether I have to use something like angular universal for it to work?

So to clarify I have a server set up with angular on it that has get requests to a database hosted on another server but that is run through a dbsm u2 rocket on my angular server.
When I run the angular application on the server I am able to make get requests no problem but when I access it from an outside computer I get a name error and get requests don't work.

Is it possible to have an angular application like this that works or does the angular application have to be run server side?

Comment: the question is not clear...

Comment: Please let me know what clarification you need further than what I've added, thank you!

Comment: how is your Angular application accessing the DB? what is the server-side tech which lets Angular communicate with DB? you're using REST APIs? what DB do you have?... architecturally, DB servers shouldn't have access to public internet; the get requests are used to communicate from your client-side to server-side and this server-side has access to your DB.